# Jenkins can't locate directory in git repo

Tags: git, ubuntu, jenkins

I have installed jenkins on an ssh server on my ubuntu machine. I've created a job that builds a c++ project.

The job executes the shell command:

```
cd exact-arithmetic/
qmake exact-arithmetic.pro
make
```

When the job builds I receive the following error

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/integerBuild
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository REPONAME
 > git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/integerBuild # timeout=10 
Fetching upstream changes from REPONAME
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress REPONAME +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config remote.origin.url REPONAME # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url REPONAME # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from REPONAME
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress REPONAME +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision d1d90929149a6de918bae21bdc6710c1965a81a5 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f d1d90929149a6de918bae21bdc6710c1965a81a5
Commit message: "Peronalisation files for git"
 > git rev-list --no-walk d1d90929149a6de918bae21bdc6710c1965a81a5 # timeout=10
[integerBuild] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins5258842808869431608.sh
+ cd exact-arithmetic/
/tmp/jenkins5258842808869431608.sh: 2: cd: can't cd to exact-arithmetic/
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...[WS-CLEANUP] done
Finished: FAILURE
```

Jenkins is having no issue connecting to the repo. When I view the github repo i see that the directory exact-arithmetic exists.

However, I have ran a job that executes the command line ls and none of my directories appear. I'm not sure what I've done wrong and seem to find much helpful information.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: does your Jenkins slave have the permission to access your folder?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you mean. Are you talking about my ssh server? Do I need to clone repo into the ssh server with git credentials?

Comment: Non, that is just a guess. I am not sure if your folder exact-arithmetic/ is part of your repo. If it has been created by another user, it might be a permission problem. You can try to ad 'ls' just before your 'cd exact-arithmetic/'. It will display the content of your current folder

Comment: It's a directory I pushed to my repo. It fails to cd to exact-arithmetic and when I ls no directories are listed.

Comment: And if you add 'pwd' after 'ls' ? pwd will give you your current directory

Comment: ls: cannot access 'pwd': No such file or directory

Comment: I meant, add another line. 'pwd' is a command

Comment: + ls
+ pwd
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/integerBuild
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...[WS-CLEANUP] done
Triggering a new build of integerBuild
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Are these directories contained in commit 929149a6de918bae21bdc6710c1965a81a5 with Commit message: "Peronalisation files for git"?

Answer (score 0):

From your comments:

- `ls` return an empty folder
- `pwd` return your current workspace: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/integerBuild

Your folder `exact-arithmetic/` does not exist.

To create it, you can add the command in your flow:

```
mkdir -p exact-arithmetic/
```

This will create the folder only if it doesn't exist yet. It will solve your error, but you will not be able to build.

My guess is that your sources have not been cloned in your git workflow.

I suggest you to replace your `git init` by

```
git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

`Git init` create a new repo. But `git clone` will get the sources of your existing repo. `git fetch` will get the changes that you want to test.

Comment: I've already done both the git init and git clone but still not helped. I'm unsure how to trouble shoot this issue or where to get information. Thanks for your help mate.

Comment: Don't do manual clones in Jenkins Pipelines. Use the `scm` step. But it seems, it checked out the repo..

Comment: Do you have a resource showing me how to execute the scm step? Am I executing the command git:Reponame in the ssh command line or as a build step in jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

1. See if you have selected the check mark for "**Delete workspace before build starts**" inside the jenkins job's configuration.
2. If the above point is true, then go to "Delete workspace before build starts" >> Advanced  >> Add >> Patterns for files to be deleted >> Exclude > **/.git/**
3. So basically, by restricting the ".git" directory from deleting, I resolved the issue.